# PyTorch regression is producing the same numbers as prediction

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch

I have applied a simple NN for regression to the traditional boston housing price dataset. The problem I’m getting is, when I make predictions using the trained model it always predicts the same numbers. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as  np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import datasets
data = datasets.load_boston()

X = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
Y = pd.DataFrame(data.target, columns=["MEDV"])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.20, random_state=1234)

import torch

x_train = torch.tensor(X_train.values, dtype=torch.float)
y_train = torch.tensor(y_train.values, dtype=torch.float)
x_test = torch.tensor(X_test.values, dtype=torch.float)
y_test = torch.tensor(y_test.values, dtype=torch.float)

import torch.nn.functional as F

class Net(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, n_feature, n_hidden, n_output):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.hidden = torch.nn.Linear(n_feature, n_hidden)
        self.predict = torch.nn.Linear(n_hidden, n_output)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.hidden(x))
        x = self.predict(x)
        return x

net = Net(n_feature=13, n_hidden=50, n_output=1)
optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(net.parameters(), lr=0.2)
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss() 


for t in range(200):
    prediction = net(x_train)

    loss = loss_func(prediction, y_train)
    print(t, loss.item())
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

**Here is the loss per epoch log:**

```
0 6414.029296875
1 3.883837028532696e+19
2 5.963952279684907e+18
3 2.1470207536047063e+18
4 7.729279495852524e+17
5 2.7825424945486234e+17
6 1.001715136546734e+17
7 3.606170935335322e+16
8 1.2982211888283648e+16
9 4673591211720704.0
10 1682493577101312.0
11 605696890503168.0
12 218050926215168.0
13 78498328739840.0
14 28259370663936.0
15 10173364043776.0
16 3662410940416.0
17 1318467796992.0
18 474648543232.0
19 170873470976.0
20 61514457088.0
21 22145208320.0
22 7972275200.0
23 2870019072.0
24 1033206912.0
25 371954528.0
26 133903616.0
27 48205360.0
28 17353982.0
29 6247483.5
30 2249145.25
31 809743.25
32 291558.65625
33 105012.1171875
34 37855.3984375
35 13678.982421875
36 4975.46826171875
37 1842.20361328125
38 714.2283325195312
39 308.15716552734375
40 161.97158813476562
41 109.34477233886719
42 90.39911651611328
43 83.57867431640625
44 81.12332153320312
45 80.23938751220703
46 79.92117309570312
47 79.8066177368164
48 79.76537322998047
49 79.75053405761719
50 79.74518585205078
51 79.7432632446289
52 79.74256896972656
53 79.74231719970703
54 79.74223327636719
55 79.74219512939453
56 79.7421875
57 79.74217987060547
58 79.74217987060547
59 79.74217987060547
60 79.74217987060547
61 79.74217987060547
62 79.74217987060547
63 79.74217987060547
64 79.74217987060547
65 79.74217987060547
66 79.74217987060547
67 79.74217987060547
68 79.74217987060547
69 79.74217987060547
70 79.74217987060547
71 79.74217987060547
72 79.74217987060547
73 79.74217987060547
74 79.74217987060547
75 79.74217987060547
76 79.74217987060547
77 79.74217987060547
78 79.74217987060547
79 79.74217987060547
80 79.74217987060547
81 79.74217987060547
82 79.74217987060547
83 79.74217987060547
84 79.74217987060547
85 79.74217987060547
86 79.74217987060547
87 79.74217987060547
88 79.74217987060547
89 79.74217987060547
90 79.74217987060547
91 79.74217987060547
92 79.74217987060547
93 79.74217987060547
94 79.74217987060547
95 79.74217987060547
96 79.74217987060547
97 79.74217987060547
98 79.74217987060547
99 79.74217987060547
100 79.74217987060547
101 79.74217987060547
102 79.74217987060547
103 79.74217987060547
104 79.74217987060547
105 79.74217987060547
106 79.74217987060547
107 79.74217987060547
108 79.74217987060547
109 79.74217987060547
110 79.74217987060547
111 79.74217987060547
112 79.74217987060547
113 79.74217987060547
114 79.74217987060547
115 79.74217987060547
116 79.74217987060547
117 79.74217987060547
118 79.74217987060547
119 79.74217987060547
120 79.74217987060547
121 79.74217987060547
122 79.74217987060547
123 79.74217987060547
124 79.74217987060547
125 79.74217987060547
126 79.74217987060547
127 79.74217987060547
128 79.74217987060547
129 79.74217987060547
130 79.74217987060547
131 79.74217987060547
132 79.74217987060547
133 79.74217987060547
134 79.74217987060547
135 79.74217987060547
136 79.74217987060547
137 79.74217987060547
138 79.74217987060547
139 79.74217987060547
140 79.74217987060547
141 79.74217987060547
142 79.74217987060547
143 79.74217987060547
144 79.74217987060547
145 79.74217987060547
146 79.74217987060547
147 79.74217987060547
148 79.74217987060547
149 79.74217987060547
150 79.74217987060547
151 79.74217987060547
152 79.74217987060547
153 79.74217987060547
154 79.74217987060547
155 79.74217987060547
156 79.74217987060547
157 79.74217987060547
158 79.74217987060547
159 79.74217987060547
160 79.74217987060547
161 79.74217987060547
162 79.74217987060547
163 79.74217987060547
164 79.74217987060547
165 79.74217987060547
166 79.74217987060547
167 79.74217987060547
168 79.74217987060547
169 79.74217987060547
170 79.74217987060547
171 79.74217987060547
172 79.74217987060547
173 79.74217987060547
174 79.74217987060547
175 79.74217987060547
176 79.74217987060547
177 79.74217987060547
178 79.74217987060547
179 79.74217987060547
180 79.74217987060547
181 79.74217987060547
182 79.74217987060547
183 79.74217987060547
184 79.74217987060547
185 79.74217987060547
186 79.74217987060547
187 79.74217987060547
188 79.74217987060547
189 79.74217987060547
190 79.74217987060547
191 79.74217987060547
192 79.74217987060547
193 79.74217987060547
194 79.74217987060547
195 79.74217987060547
196 79.74217987060547
197 79.74217987060547
198 79.74217987060547
199 79.74217987060547
```

**After training the model, I’ve used the following code to make predictions:**

```
with torch.no_grad():
    y_val = net(x_test)
```

**When I print the predictions I get the following results:**

```
tensor([[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099],
[22.4099]])
```

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while but did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the model does not fit to your dataset well.
After inspecting your code, I think I could guess where went wrong.

The way you perform gradient descent is somehow incorrect to me. Bear in mind that we are optimizing on a non-convex function. So pack the whole train dataset in a batch would not work, and your model will be stuck in a local-minium, which always not good enough. This could turn into a more complicated discussion with quite a lengthy explanation. I found a good reference for you to understand why we cannot do that on a non-convex function from [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/batch-mini-batch-stochastic-gradient-descent-7a62ecba642a).

My suggestion is to try to sample your training data into small batch-size and run forward-backward update with small batches with a loop inside your epoch loop. for instance, from 8 to 96, and see how that works. In your toy example, you could shuffle your training data each epoch and select your mini-batch one by one. If you wanted to go fancier(or, more standard for performing deep learning in Pytorch), you could write a PyTorch dataset to handle data loading and batching. The loss of your training data should be very small if you are doing this correctly.

Edit:

You might also want to gradually decrease your learning rate, say, 10 times after every 60 epochs to get a better-optimized loss function.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize your features before you pass them to the model. Normalize the target as well.

The reason is clear if you look at the size of your loss values. You are using MSEloss so it is noticeable that your target range must be very very large. This messes up the gradient calculations. Neural networks like normalized features.